# Subtract one day in XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, datetime

How to subtract one day in XMLGregorianCalendar?
Also while subtracting how to cope up with following problems :

- it does not goes to a negative value in case of first day of the month
- in case of 1st Jan of a year, where it needs to go back to a previus year

and other similar stuffs.

Please do not suggest to use any other library like Joda-Time. I know they are great, but I need to get this done using XMLGregorianCalendar only.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just convert to a normal `GregorianCalendar`, do the arithmetic there, then convert back:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = xmlCalendar.toGregorianCalendar();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
xmlCalendar = datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
```

(This assumes you already have a `DatatypeFactory` of course. You can always call `DatatypeFactory.newInstance()` if necessary.)

Comment: Will this take care of all the potential worries regarding change of month and year? @Jon Skeet

Comment: @sam100rav: Yes. You may want to specify the time zone explicitly though.

Comment: Initially, xmlGregorianCalendar has timezone set in it, but after conversion also do I have to set the time zone again?

Comment: @sam100rav: If it already has a time zone, then `toGregorianCalendar` will preserve that, it looks like. I suggest you write unit tests to validate...

Answer (score 6):

`XMLGregorianCalendar` has an `add(Duration)` method which you could also use for this computation without needing to convert to a `GregorianCalendar` first. Here's an example:

```
DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar calendar1 = ...;
XMLGregorianCalendar calendar2 = (XMLGregorianCalendar) calendar1.clone();
calendar2.add(df.newDuration("-P1D"));
```

Comment: To add a duration I have to use "P1D" literal.